# Maven pom with zipped native dll in classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dll, pom.xml

I have a maven project that uses a jar with dll. I am able to add the jar with no problem but the dll is in a zipped file and I am trying to add it to the project classpath.
My question is, how do I unzip and add the dll to the classpath and if that cannot be done I can extract manually but how do I add the dll to the classpath using pom ? 
For now I have something like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>unpack</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>unpack</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>my-group-id</groupId>
              <artifactId>my-artifactId</artifactId>
              <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
              <type>zip</type>
              <overWrite>true</overWrite>
              <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Why unpacking it as a step in the build process? Would it not be simpler to have it on the classpath in your module? Or is the dll also properly versioned as a Maven artifact?

Comment: @hotzst the dll is generated from another project as a zipped file with other properties. I can unzip it myself but I'd just like to add it to the classpath. Thanks